# I keep getting errors, although I deleted the text causing the error

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I keep getting the following errors:

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a. ...ck \emph{Revisiting Spacetrack Report #3} 

You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode. ...ck \emph{Revisiting Spacetrack Report #3}
```

It first occurred when I inserted/added a new report to my Bibtex-file. The title included a hash (Revisting Spacetrack Report #3) which is apparently not allowed. Therefore, I changed the title and deleted the hash, but I kept getting the same error.

I deleted the paragraph in question in the bibtex file and deleted the citation in the latex file, but I still have the error and am not able to compile my file. Saving, restarting TeXStudio, and even the computer itself did not help.

What is causing the troubles?

Comment: Use `\#` instead of `#`.  Delete the `.bbl` file and then recompile (to regenerate the bibliography).

Comment: Is this comment answering the question? If so, it would be nice if Nicolas could confirm this and @StevenB.Segletes could turn the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 4):

It is important to keep in mind that LaTeX does not, necessarily, regenerate all facets of a document from scratch upon each compilation.  In fact, it often relies on multiple passes so that information from compile-pass #1 can be used as part of the input for compile-pass #2.

Many modern implementations of LaTeX (e.g., MikTeX and others) will automatically multi-pass the compiler for you, *if it determines that it is needed.*  And that latter clause is the key, which can be a curse to new users, because it can give the impression that everything is regenerated with each compilation in one fell swoop.

In the OP's case, there was a syntax error in the .bib file of using `#` instead of the text-version of the hash mark, which is properly `\#`.  Upon your initial compilation following the addition of that new erroneously formatted reference, the BibTex phase of compilation ran successfully and stored the erroneous `#` in the .bbl file, where all the bib item information is stored for the next compiler pass.  When the LaTeX phase of compilation was reran, it complained with an error over the improper use of `#` instead of `\#`.

And here's the rub: a auto-multi-pass LaTeX implementation will not automatically rerun the BibTeX phase of recompilation unless the LaTeX phase of compilation tells it that a new `\cite` label has been added to your document, requiring additional bibliographic information to be generated for your document's reference list.

So even when you remove the offending `#` from your bib file, or remove the `\cite` of that item from your document, the BibTeX phase of recompilation will not be called upon to revise the bib item information stored in the .bbl file.

You actually have to delete the .bbl file, which will force the LaTeX implementation (e.g., MikTeX) to understand that you need a new BibTeX compiler pass to generate bibliography information, using the corrected bib file to regenerate a correct .bbl file.

---

As a postscript, this class of problem can often happen for non-bibliography issues as well, requiring the deletion of some compiler-pass #1 file.  Most often, it is the .aux file where information is stored that, if incorrect, can confound a compilation.

So the lesson is to be ready to delete these ancillary files, if necessary, after correcting certain classes of error in your document.